# How do I keep show() function open

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have the following script, but when I move my cursor from `#menu`, `#dropdown` disappears. How do I keep `.dropdown` open?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".menu").hover(function() {
   $(".dropdown").show();        
}, function() {
   $(".dropdown").hide();
 });        
});
```

HTML

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li class="menu">
       <a href="#">Dropdown</a>
       <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Sub Page</a></li>
       </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Remove your line of code that hides it?

Comment: Sorry? I didn't get you.

Comment: Remove `$(".dropdown").hide();`

Comment: @Satpal I want to keep both as it is dropdown menu.

Comment: @Swagata: You're saying you want it to hide, because it's a dropdown menu, but you don't want it to hide when you move the cursor off. When do you want it to hide?

Comment: @ColinDeClue when I move cursor from `.menu`. It has a sub page. I don't it to hide if cursor on sub page too.

Comment: @Swagata see the CSS solution below. It works as you describe.

Comment: @War10ck I did, thanks but I am using different css and different function here. So I don't want to use css.

Comment: I was using `.toggle()` but it hides when I want to click on it's sub links.

Comment: @Swagata: Your comment `when I move cursor from .menu` and your question `but when I move my cursor from #menu, #dropdown disappears.` state opposite things. What do you want to happen? I used what you have in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fj4Gs/), and it works how you'd want it to.

Comment: Let's step back a moment. You have no `IDs` in your entire markup. (i.e. `#menu` and `#dropdown` are both invalid). What are you trying to do and which elements do you want to do it with?

Comment: I am trying to create a simple toggle collapse menu with jquery. I can create with css, but this time wanna go with jquery. For an example I have 3 navigation links i.e. Home, Pages, About. Pages has another link inside it i.e. Sub-Page. So when mouse hover on `Pages`, it will show `Sub-Page` and if I move my cursor from there, `Sub-Page` will disappear.

Comment: See this website http://resie.ppparticularity.com/. I'm trying to achieve the same but with jquery and on hover function.

Comment: @Swagata Added a second JavaScript solution to my answer below. Check it out and let me know what you thing.

Comment: @War10ck Thanks, that's what I needed and sorry for confusing you all with my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish what you're trying to do without using JS at all. Here is a pure CSS solution:

**Solution 1:**

*HTML:*

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li class="menu">
       <a href="#">Dropdown</a>
       <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Sub Page</a></li>
       </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

*CSS:*

```
.dropdown {
    display: none;
}
.menu:hover > .dropdown {
    display: block;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9X7yf/)**

**Solution 2:**

*HTML:*

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li class="menu">
       <a href="#">Dropdown</a>
       <ul class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="#">Sub Page</a></li>
       </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

*CSS:*

```
.dropdown {
    display: none;
}
```

*JavaScript:*

```
$(function () {

    var $dropdown = $('.dropdown'),
        $menu = $('.menu'),
        timeout;

    $menu.on('mouseenter', function () {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        $dropdown.show();   
    }).on('mouseleave', function () {
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            $dropdown.hide();   
        }, 200);
    });

    $dropdown.on('mouseenter', function () {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        $dropdown.show();   
    }).on('mouseleave', function () {
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            $dropdown.hide();   
        }, 200);
    });    

});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/s68s6/)**

Comment: This will, in fact, not do what he's trying to do. This will recreate what currently happens, which is not what he wants. To do what he wants, he does need JS.

Comment: @ColinDeClue Did you check the fiddle. In Chrome 32 it works. When I hover over ***Dropdown*** the ***Sub Page*** link appears. I'm then able to click on the ***Sub Page*** link or move off the link if I want the menu to hide. If this is not right, then the OP needs to provide more clarification. Works like any simple drop down menu does. Because the `ul.dropdown` is wrapped in the `li.menu` it works just fine.

Comment: I'm using jquery here, not css.

Comment: @Swagata No need for jQuery here. It is a waste. CSS is not another library. It's just styling. You can eliminate the JS all together. No reason to use JavaScript for the functionality you describe. Styling is all that is necessary. Simply place the CSS in a `<style>` block or more preferably an external stylesheet and link to it. Also it is important to note that if the user has JavaScript disabled, the jQuery dropdown will not work. This however will.

Comment: @War10ck: I agree that this does what a normal dropdown would do (and is preferable to the js solution). However, if you read his question, he states `when I move my cursor from #menu, #dropdown disappears. How do I keep .dropdown open?`. Ignoring the ID and classname confusion, your css will perform exactly the same thing (because that's what a dropdown should do)

Comment: @ColinDeClue Must be missing the point here. There are no elements with id `menu` or `class`...

Comment: Right. I'm assuming he means `.menu` and `.dropdown`, because that's what is in both his code and his markup.

Comment: @ColinDeClue Ok I think I'm following you now. This question is highly confusing.

Answer (score 0):

`.hover` gets code to run on mouse leave in its another(2nd) parameter. If you wanna keep the menu opened, use `.mouseenter` event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".menu").mouseenter(function() {
      $(".dropdown").show(); 
   });        
});
```

Comment: This shows the menu but never hides it. I presume the OP wants the typical behavior of a drop down menu. Show on `hover. Show while in menu (i.e. show when `hovering` inside the menu) and hide on exit.